# Is it Possible to use OpenPyXl to create Excel Slicer objects for Charts/Pivot Charts?

Tags: excel, python-3.x, openpyxl, xlsxwriter

I'm currently using xlsx writer and openpyxl to create and edit worksheets.  I have constructed dataframes which store relative statistics, and after publishing them to an excel sheet I'd like to include some basic user interaction features.

Specifically, I was wondering if it is possible to create Excel Slicer objects and pair them with some line/bar/etc charts using OpenPyXl (or anopther api) so that subsets of the population can be visualized.

Comment: I don't think Slicer objects are part of the OOXML specification in which case this isn't going to be possible.

Comment: aw, bummer- i was hoping i was just missing something in the documentation.  thank you!

do you think it would be possible in xlwings?  their documentation seems like it's undergoing some changes, but i have been able to reproduce work using openpxyl and xlsx writer to a great extent.