# I cannot load my workbook using Openpyxl in Python

Tags: python, openpyxl

I have an excel file that has 4 different worksheets and when I try to load my data as following:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
template = "template.xlsx"
ws = load_workbook(template)
```

I get the error:

> C:\Users\XX\PycharmProjects\JSONtoExcel\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet_reader.py:312:
> UserWarning: Slicer List extension is not supported and will be
> removed   warn(msg)

Comment: Are there pivot slices in the excel book? If so these were not supported by openpyxl;https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54028693/is-it-possible-to-use-openpyxl-to-create-excel-slicer-objects-for-charts-pivot-c

Comment: Oh! so which approach can I use? because I am using Pivot slices. I want to fill the data in a worksheet that doesn't have pivot table but in another worksheet I have the PIVOT

Comment: It's only a warning message so the workbook should still open. You should be able to access other sheets. Otherwise there is no workaround for openpyxl. Charlie Clark mentioned this a few years back, maybe he might comment now if this will change in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If its not messing around with your, data you can use the below code to silence the warnings

```
import warnings

warnings.filterwarnings('ignore', category=UserWarning, module='openpyxl')
```